# Force an Excel file to be associated with a VSTO addin

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

This is my use case:
I need to develop a excel VSTO add-in that prevents a user from accessing a excel file unless the add-in is installed. This add-in basically authenticates the current user, and if that is successful, it will grant them access to the file. Basically I need a way to protect a file that uses my own authentication (and not the built-in password protection provided by Microsoft. Why? Because I need to be able to revoke access to the file and a local password would prevent me from doing so)

I know how to write the add-in, what I don't know is, how do I force a file to be associated with that plugin? I tried using a custom property, but that is very hack-able. Basically, I would have a custom property that says: "use this add-in", but a knowledgeable user could just go in Advanced Properties and simply delete it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be for you to use COM Add-ins, as they do not distribute the code to the user and can't be easily hacked. A simple Add-in, that uses .XLA or .XLAM files are simply password protected VBA projects that can be hacked.

Now, for your workbook, I suggest you encrypt and scramble all the data and use your COM Add-in to decrypt your data and use a function to prevent saving the workbook un-encrypted. You could just override the Workbook_OnSave method to encrypt on saving. Also disable copying of cell values.

For this part, I don't know if this is possible, but you would need to override user access to VBA editor, so they couldn't walk around your add-in protections and also disable the access to options menu to disable the Add-in. That can be achieved by overwriting the Excels shortcut keys and hiding the menu bar.

Again, for the last part, I don't know if it's actually possible to limit user access to VBA editor. I think it would be pretty similar as limiting access to Add-in controls by overriding ALT+F11 shortcut and just hiding the developers tab as a whole.

Well that's my two cents, good luck!

Comment: Thank for the quick reply. My main issue is, how do I make a particular file use my add-in, or know that it needs it? How would my add-in know which files need it? Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Well, you could override the Workbooks.open method, to check if the add-in is active. If not - don't decrypt the data and promt the user to use your add-in. If add-in is present then continue with authentication

Comment: It turns out there is no way to encrypt a file without a password. And I don't want to set a password because I don't want the user to be prompted with one and I can't programatically pass it (unless I do some hacky SendKeys command which works half the time). Instead I wrote a program that is associated with a custom extension which represents a encrypted excel file. When the user opens it, it gets decrypted back into a excel file and then by overriding the WorkbookSave and Open methods I encrypt it back when the user is done with it. Its not bulletproof but it will do for now...

Comment: @TimA. How did you implement the encryption via Excel's WorkbookSave? I would do the decryption in the external program. However, this will not work with the new encryption, since the external program does not know when the file will be closed.